# Conectar a un servidor FTP desde Java

Tags: java, ftpclient

Basado en las recomendaciones de que **no es recomendable almacenar imágenes en base de datos**, quiero guardar las imágenes en un directorio especifico ubicado en un servidor Linux fedora usando el protocolo `FTP`. Trato de obtener conexión con el servidor:

```
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;

private final Action action = new AbstractAction() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        try {
            final FTPClient fTPClient = new FTPClient();
            
            fTPClient.connect("ftp://192.168.1.10");
            fTPClient.login("", "");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Conectado");
        } catch (final HeadlessException | NumberFormatException exception) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Se produjo un error, vuelve a intentarlo.", "SIET", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            System.err.println("Error registrar equipo: " + exception.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Se produjo un error, vuelve a intentarlo.", "SIET", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            Logger.getLogger(RegistrarEquipo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
};
```

pero me devuelve el siguiente error: `java.net.UnknownHostException: ftp://192.168.1.10: invalid IPv6 address`. Sin embargo, si la dirección `ftp://192.168.1.10` lo llevo al navegador obtengo la conexion y el acceso.

Comment: Proablemente FTPClient (por cierto, deberías especificar qué librería usas si quieres ayuda) quiera saber la IP y el puerto. `ftp://192.168.1.0`  NO es la IP, es una URL que incluye la IP pero también el protocolo. Parece que el cliente no sabe tratar con URL, y lo intenta convertir a una IPv6 (por los `:`, supongo) y falla. Prueba con `192.168.1.0` a secas. Lee la documentación de la librería para saber qué parámetro espera.

Comment: librería agregada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leída la documentación de [connect(String hostname)](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/javadocs/api-3.6/org/apache/commons/net/SocketClient.html#connect(java.lang.String)), que dice:

> Opens a Socket connected to a remote host at the current default port and originating from the current host at a system assigned port. Before returning, *connectAction*() is called to perform connection initialization actions.
> Parameters:
> hostname - The name of the remote host.

Lo que espera no es una URL sino el nombre del servidor, que puede ser tanto el nombre DNS como la IP.

Tal como indiqué en el comentario, `ftp://192.168.1.0` no es un hostname sino una URL (el hostname no indica el protocolo, por ejemplo). FTPClient intenta parsear ese String como un hostname y, como tiene `:`, piensa que es una IPv6 y la intenta analizar; por eso el mensaje que te sale de que no es una IPv6 válida.

Usa directamente la IP del servidor

```
fTPClient.connect("192.168.1.10");
```